# error on java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider==null

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, illegalargumentexception

I published my application to android market. I got error in my home page. Somebody wrote crash error. But  this application is perfectly working in my real device. I added permission also. 
My error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.karthi.locationspeecher/com.android.locationspeecher.LocationSpeecher}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider==null
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider==null
at android.location.LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.java:1017)
at com.android.locationspeecher.LocationSpeecher.onCreate(LocationSpeecher.java:84)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
... 11 more
```

LocationManager:

```
 LocationManager locationManager; 
            String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE; 
            locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context); 

            Criteria crta = new Criteria(); 
            crta.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE); 
            crta.setAltitudeRequired(false); 
            crta.setBearingRequired(false); 
            crta.setCostAllowed(true); 
            crta.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW); 
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(crta, true); 

         // String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER; 
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider); 
            updateWithNewLocation(location); 

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 10, locationListener); 
            }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting this error most probably, due to un-availability of `GPS Providers`. Please ask the person to check settings if `Gps Provider` or `Network Provider` has been enabled into Location settings.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to add `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` or `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` to your Manifest file, this solved the issue for me (all providers were already enabled in the location settings).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding  :

`[assembly: UsesPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Manifest.Permission.Internet)]'

in assemlyInfo.cs to give permission