# Geocoder, locationName == null

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoding, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm working on a social event app where users can posts events and have people see those events on a map or list. I'm currently working on trying to geocode the location address that I have in my database and converting it into lat and long coords. I've looked over the code dozens of times and get the same error. "locationName == null" The only conclusion I've come to is that I'm not actually pulling any data from the database and I'm sending null vales to the geocoder which is giving me this error. I'm using Android Studio with Google Firestore as my databse. Hopefully some fresh eyes can give me some insight into this issue. Let me know if you need see other relevant code snippets.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener, ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ImageButton notifyButton;
private ImageButton messagesButton;
private ImageButton exploreButton;
private ImageButton profileButton;

private double lat;
private double lng;
private String address;
private String city;
private String state;
private int zipcode;

private LatLng geoCoord;

/**
 * Request code for location permission request.
 *
 * @see #onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[])
 */
private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

/**
 * Flag indicating whether a requested permission has been denied after returning in
 * {@link #onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[])}.
 */
private boolean mPermissionDenied = false;

private GoogleMap mMap;
private MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    notifyButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.notifyButton);
    notifyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent main = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotifyActivity.class);
            startActivity(main);
        }
    });

    messagesButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.messagesButton);
    messagesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent main = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MessengerActivity.class);
            startActivity(main);
        }
    });

    exploreButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.exploreButton);
    exploreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent main = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ExploreActivity.class);
            startActivity(main);
        }
    });

    profileButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.profileButton);
    profileButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent main = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(main);
        }
    });



    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


}




/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
    enableMyLocation();


    try {
        // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
        // in a raw resource file.
        boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                        this, R.raw.style_json));

        if (!success) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
        }
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
    }
    // Position the map's camera near Sydney, Australia.

    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(-34, 151)));
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(geoLocate()));
}

private void enableMyLocation() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Permission to access the location is missing.
        PermissionUtils.requestPermission(this, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, true);
    } else if (mMap != null) {
        // Access to the location has been granted to the app.
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Current Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Return false so that we don't consume the event and the default behavior still occurs
    // (the camera animates to the user's current position).
    return false;
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode != LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        return;
    }

    if (PermissionUtils.isPermissionGranted(permissions, grantResults,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        // Enable the my location layer if the permission has been granted.
        enableMyLocation();
    } else {
        // Display the missing permission error dialog when the fragments resume.
        mPermissionDenied = true;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResumeFragments() {
    super.onResumeFragments();
    if (mPermissionDenied) {
        // Permission was not granted, display error dialog.
        showMissingPermissionError();
        mPermissionDenied = false;
    }
}

/**
 * Displays a dialog with error message explaining that the location permission is missing.
 */
private void showMissingPermissionError() {
    PermissionUtils.PermissionDeniedDialog
            .newInstance(true).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}

public LatLng geoLocate() {
    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
    List <Address> list;
    try{
        list = gc.getFromLocationName(getFullAddress(), 1);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {

        return null;
    }
    Address add = list.get(0);
    String locality = add.getLocality();
    Toast.makeText(this, locality, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return new LatLng(add.getLatitude(), add.getLongitude());

}

public String getFullAddress() {
    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("events").document("House Party");
    docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            Event event = documentSnapshot.toObject(Event.class);
            address = event.getAddress() + ", " + event.getCity() + ", " + event.getState() + " " + event.getZipcode();
        }
    });
    return address;
}
```

}

**Error Log**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.example.android.gathr, PID: 8599
                                                                     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: locationName == null
                                                                         at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocationName(Geocoder.java:171)
                                                                         at com.example.android.gathr.MainActivity$override.geoLocate(MainActivity.java:232)
                                                                         at com.example.android.gathr.MainActivity$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
                                                                         at com.example.android.gathr.MainActivity.geoLocate(MainActivity.java:0)
                                                                         at com.example.android.gathr.MainActivity$override.onMapReady(MainActivity.java:169)
                                                                         at com.example.android.gathr.MainActivity$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
                                                                         at com.example.android.gathr.MainActivity.onMapReady(MainActivity.java:0)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzak.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzaq.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:507)
                                                                         at gl.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11518448:20)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bf.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11518448:5)
                                                                         at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bc.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11518448:5)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6642)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

**EDIT:**

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("BJ");
 docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() 
 {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    City city = documentSnapshot.toObject(City.class);
    }
   });
```

So I saved the data as an object in my database and pulled from the database based off the above code. I pulled the address elements stored them in an address variable and let the geolocate method convert that code into a lat and long coordinate.

Comment: No one can find lat-long for null address.

Comment: @HareshChhelana I know, but I'm wondering why the address I'm trying to pull is null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error on java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider==null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524443/error-on-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-provider-null)

Comment: Can you please post code how you can pull address ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana updated the code to reflect how I did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `getFullAddress()` you call what I assume is an asynchronous operation (`docRef.get()`) to set `address` but you return `address` immediately without waiting for the listener you added to execute.

To get around this you could move the geocoding into the `onSuccess` callback, which would have the nice side-effect of only doing the Geocode if the document retrieval worked.

Comment: I figured it out